# know that skspritenode has completely moved over another skspritenode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to figure out that a SKSpriteNode has completely iterated over another `SKSpriteNode`.  **This the code I have come up with so far,**

```
if (node.frame.maxY == player.frame.minY) {
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collisionTypes.vortex.rawValue
}
```

I know it's simple enough, but I'm lost here.

Comment: do you mean on top of? or completely passed through?

Comment: completely passed through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the contactTestBitMask properties of both objects. then detect when they collide in the didBegin func and then detect when they stop colliding in the didEnd func

```
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionTypes.bullet.rawValue
bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionTypes.player.rawValue

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    //detect your collision and do what you need to do
    //maybe set a bool to true if you have multiple collision types
}

func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    //check that the above collison is the one that ended
    //run appropriate code for end collision
}
```